# error "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" after enable trigger in ef6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, triggers

By following the command, I delete the row of the table without any problems.

```
using (var context = new SamenEntities())
{
    var person = context.regs.Where(c => c.code == ID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (person != null)
    {
        context.regs.Remove(person);
        context.SaveChanges();
        clearformsearch();
    }
}
```

Now I want to activate the following trigger in the database :

```
    USE [Samen]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[delete_after_project]    Script Date: 9/11/2018 12:46:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[delete_after_project]
ON [dbo].[reg]
AFTER Delete
AS 
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @C_ID AS int
SELECT @C_ID = code FROM deleted 
DELETE FROM project
WHERE id_person = @C_ID
END
```

After activating the trigger, I receive the following error in SaveChange :

> **System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:** 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details.'

Comment: ...so what is the inner exception?

Comment: @PaulAbbott , `SqlException: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.`

Comment: Did you leave off the `END` from your trigger when you copied it or is it actually missing?

Comment: @PaulAbbott , I did not copy, trigger code updated

Comment: Why don't you have cascaded delete?

Comment: +1 on cascade delete. Regarding the error I suspect that the trigger might be raising an exception resulting in the EF transaction not completing successfully. Avoid the trigger and set up the DB & EF relationships to cascade on delete.

Comment: @StevePy , So I deleted the trigger and used the cascade. Thankful